# Laptop randomly cannot find SSD

Tags: boot, laptop, ssd

I bought an SSD for my laptop to replace my HDD. SSD is "Intel Embedded 5" 120 GB. When it works - it works no problem with that. But sometimes when I leave the laptop running during the night when I wake up it asks me for a boot drive like no SSD is found in the system. I double check the BIOS and there is no drive detected. Then I power off the laptop then power on again and it starts booting like the SSD has always been inside. Any Ideas why this may happen.

Details:
Laptop : Lenovo Flex 2 - 15
SSD : Intel Embedded 5 - 120 GB
OS : Windows 10
RAM : 8 GB DDR3L
BIOS is always update to it's latest version available in the US site.

if you need any details please leave a comment.

EDIT: I was finally there when the issue happened.

The exact sequence of events is the following: 
 1. Windows Hangs
 2. BSOD with stopcode : UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION
 3. Automatic reboot
 4. No boot drive detected so the BIOS is stuck at [[image]this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpzyB.jpg)
 5. Going do the bios yields: Hard Disk : Not Installed
 6. Hold the power button till the laptop is all silent
 7. Power it on again
 8. Windows boots and all is normal

If you need anymore information I am happy to provide it but I still don't understand whether it is hardware problem or BIOS problem. I doubt it is windows is fault though.

Answer (score 0):

One of two issues is more than likely.

1. You're in BIOS mode when you should be in UEFI mode (Or vice versa).
2. You need to disable Secure Boot.

EDIT: Based on additional information in the question I'm going to deem this a bad SATA controller and/or drive.

Comment: I am in UEFI mode currently, and have been since I got the laptop. But why should I be in BIOS mode

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov Is secure boot enabled?

Comment: It was enabled. but that was not the problem as it happened again after I disabled it. It is still disabled though

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov Sounds like a bad controller and/or drive then.

Comment: “You need to disable Secure Boot.” - Why? It’s an optional feature of UEFI. It has nothing to do with the authors problem

Comment: @Ramhound I had this issue personally on a computer; the UEFI hardware signature did not allow booting from a newly installed drive.

Comment: @Mooseman Sounds like a different issue entirely